# How to increase the performance of a file upload using native sftp functions and fwrite in PHP

Tags: php, upload, sftp, fwrite, ssh2-sftp

Hi I am using the following code to upload a huge file (500MB) to a sftp server.

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port, null);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$connection_string = ((int) $sftp) . $remotePath . $remoteFilename;
$stream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . $connection_string, 'w');
$source = fopen($localFilepath, 'r');

if (!$stream) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create file: ' . $connection_string);
}

while (!feof($source)) {
    // Chunk size 32 MB
    if (fwrite($stream, fread($source, 33554432)) === false) {
        throw new Exception('Could not send data: ' . $connection_string);
    }
}

fclose($source);
fclose($stream);
```

But the upload is **very** slow. The code is running on Google Cloud Run. The upload speed is around 8 MiB/s.

I also tried to use lftp via shell_exec but this lead to even more issues due to Cloud Run.

The uplink can't be the problem as I can send files via CURL post without any issues.

Anyone able to help here?

Many thanks and best,
intxcc

Comment: With ssh2_scp_send I wasn't sure because it is another protocol, isn't it?
With phpseclib I had problems with some obscure public key algorithms. As it is a requirement, that the user can set the key algorithm and wanted all of them I thought native sftp would be the safest bet.

Comment: Sure, usually they support it - but in this case I needed a stable solution. So **most** support it does not work. Actually the user can choose between scp and sftp, so when they choose sftp I'm pretty sure they expect sftp. Resolving the rare edge case of sftp without scp after 1 year of this working doesn't sound like fun ^^

Comment: I am not sure you are aware that I already fixed this and answered the question (just was not able to find the answer before, which is why I am posting this here)

The issue was indeed the chunk size of the fwrite. Its per default just a few KB, because it is meant to be used on the filesystem usually.
So yeah, with just the info provided in the question it could have been possible that native sftp is just very bad. But it seems that it is not :)

`stream_set_chunk_size($stream, 1024 * 1024);` fixed this issue

Comment: Thanks nevertheless for your input!
Edit: yeah I need to wait 2 days before I am able to approve my own answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that even though 32MB are read and then written to the sftp stream, fwrite will chunk at a different size. I think just a few KB.

For filesystems (which is the usual case with fwrite) this is fine, but not with high latency due to fwriting to a remote server.

So the solution is to increase the chunk size of the sftp stream with

```
stream_set_chunk_size($stream, 1024 * 1024);
```

So the final working code is:

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port, null);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$connection_string = ((int) $sftp) . $remotePath . $remoteFilename;
$stream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . $connection_string, 'w');
$source = fopen($localFilepath, 'r');

// Stream chunk size 1 MB
stream_set_chunk_size($stream, 1024 * 1024);

if (!$stream) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create file: ' . $connection_string);
}

while (!feof($source)) {
    // Chunk size 32 MB
    if (fwrite($stream, fread($source, 33554432)) === false) {
        throw new Exception('Could not send data: ' . $connection_string);
    }
}

fclose($source);
fclose($stream);
```

Hope this helps the next person that is getting gray hair trying to figure that out ;)